# How to mask particular column of a table for particular user in Oracle

Tags: oracle

Oracle Data masking. How do I mask the data by XXX of a particular column of Table.

RLS policy doesn't work for me.

For security reasons the value is replaced by XXX, so actual value should remain same, and it should be automated for the user

Comment: Why does VPD not work for you? Have you tried [column masking](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e16543/vpd.htm#i1014682)? Is the issue that you can make that work but want something (`XXX`) instead of `null` in the masked column - and if so why, and why the aversion to a view to achieve that?

Comment: Because I just want to hide the data, not change the data for the user. So when i check condition masked_column_name="XYZ" it fails since it has null value for that user

Comment: But if the user is supplying the `masked_column_name` value, hiding it doesn't really help - if you get a row back you know the value must be `XYZ`, whether it's shown as `XXX` or null, surely? You can't have the value hidden and not hidden at the same time, with a simple select anyway. And isn't hiding it with `null` better than 'changing' it to `XXX`?

Comment: this value might come from joins with other tables(user not entering manually) maybe at an application level.

Comment: If the user isn't querying the table directly, and the application does the filtering, can't the application do the masking as well? You could enforce both if the application is connecting as a different DB user (e.g. via connection pooling).

Answer (score 2):

```
Revoke select on your_table from particular_user;

create view view_on_table as
select col1, col2, 'xxx' as particular_column, col3
from your table;

grant select on view_on_table to particular_user;
```

:)

Comment: Thanks but it should not be a view. It has to be a direct "Select" on table by the user

Comment: @joe why shouldn't it?

Comment: because it is jus an access control on table column for a particular schema

Answer (score 2):

Oracle's Virtual Private Database is the only way I know of to make this happen, given your constraint that this must be a direct query against the table: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/security/index-088277.html

Comment: Thanks for help David
But there was a problem with this approach joins and conditions on that columns fail :(

Comment: I don't think that you're going to get around that. If the value is masked from the user yet you want to be able to use the value in predicates then it's not really masked at all. It sounds like any solution to this would have to be outside of the database in the application layer. A "creative" solution might be possible if you can update the question with more details about the data and the problem.

Comment: Okay Imagine a scenario
there are 2 schemas A and B
There is table say employee in A of which empname should be hidden from B
So when B says select empname from A.employees .. it will be hidden or XXX
But when B makes a join of empname from A.employees  with  empname from B.employees the join fails since it is null for B

Comment: @joe - if that worked then you'd be revealing that the `empname` from `B` exists in `A`, which would also make hiding it pointless, unless you're also masking the `empname` from `A`. You might still be able to do this with view, as long as the person doing the querying isn't `A` or `B`, but you haven't said why views are not permitted. I don't think you're going to get anywhere unless you update the question with a lot more information about what you're trying to achieve, and how (and why) you're constrained in the approach you can take.

Comment: view doesnt work because schema B hits select * from employee and not v_employee.